# MySQL time diff grouped by day

Tags: mysql

I have a table from which I'm trying to extracted summed timediff information grouped by days. I don't really know if this is possible
Table columns: mode_type, start_time.
A record exists in this table for each time an employee starts or stops a timer. mode_type = 1 for start, mode_type = 0 for stop.

I'd like to return a sum of the seconds used for each day in the last 30 days.
E.g:

```
date, seconds_used
02/04/2014, 25
03/04/2014, 12415
04/04/2014, 925
```

Currently I can return a list of seconds used per mode_type and date but this required later calc in PHP.

```
SELECT
      mode_type,
      Sum(Unix_Timestamp(start_time)) AS time,
      start_time
    FROM
      activations
    WHERE
      start_time < Date(Now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY
      mode_type, Day(start_time)
    ORDER BY
      start_time
```

I'm stuck... is this possible or do I need to do revert to calculating the diff in PHP post request?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this:

```
SELECT  DATE(start_time) AS startdate, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),start_time)) AS secs
FROM    activations
GROUP BY
        startdate
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This gives me the difference from NOW until the start time but I need to know the difference from the end_time to the start_time. The start time is defined as the sum of activations on a day where the mode_type = 1. And the end time is therefore defined as the sum of activations on a day where mode_type = 0. Thanks

Comment: NOW() is the end time here

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately the start and end time need to be calculated. They are sums of various rows.The start time is defined as the sum of activations on a day where the mode_type = 1. And the end time is therefore defined as the sum of activations on a day where mode_type = 0. Thanks